# Definite articles 'the' or without 'the'

Tags: definite-article

“Reports of animal abuse are increasing” or “**the** reports of animal abuse are increasing”.

Which one is correct with 'the' or without 'the'?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct in grammar, but have subtly different implications. The first refers to (unspecified) reports, whereas the second is closer to "(these) report of animal abuse... ".
You might say that the article is correct but redundant.

Comment: I agree that the 'the' refers to reports unspecified by the sentence. I don't agree that it's redundant, for just that reason. I would expect its (correct) use in a context where someone has already mentioned reports.

Comment: OK, grammatically redundant, but not semantically redundant.